# Query contains parameters but import file contains different values [importing csv to Teradata SQL]

Tags: sql, database, teradata, sql-insert, teradatasql

I am using Teradata SQL to import a CSV file. I clicked import to activate the import operation, then typed the following

```
insert into databasename.tablename values(?,?,?,...)
```

I made sure to specify the database name as well as what I want the table to be named, and I put 13 commas--the number of columns in my CSV file.

It gives me the following error:

```
Query contains 13 parameters but Import file contains 1 data values
```

I have no idea what the issue is.

Comment: You are probably using the wrong delimiter.  Check your file to be sure it is comma delimited.  In SQL Assistant, under Tools > Options > Export/Import, make sure your delimiter is a comma (or whatever it is in your source file).

Comment: You have `teradatasql` tagged in your question. Is this work you are doing in python using `.execute` or `.executeMany`? If so can you share the code and a sample of the csv file you are importing?

Comment: The code and error in the post look to me like SQL Assistant. If not, please clarify your post. If so, please correct your tags.

Answer (score 1):

The default delimiter used by your SQL Assistant doesn't match the one used in the CSV, so it doesn't recognise all the columns.

On SQL Assistant, go to : **Tools** >> **Options** >> **Export/Import** and choose the proper delimiter so it matches the one in your CSV.

[image]